# Cannot assign to the result of this expression when assigning values to a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, couchbase

I am trying to implement the code found here : http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html#updating , at the .update method, in the following code :

```
document = database.documentWithID(u.id)
document.update({ (newRev) -> Bool in

    newRev["a"] = "A"

    return true
}, error: &error)
```

But swift is not letting me add the value into the newRev variable, telling me that I cannot assign to the result of the expresion.

Can anyone help me with a workaround for this error?

Thank you

Comment: `newRev` is likely an immutable dictionary so you can't assign to it.

Comment: You're using an `NSDictionary`, which is immutable. You need to use an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you, that made me look inside the framework and I found out that the `NSMutableDictionary` is `newRev.properties`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help I found the solution myself, the mistake in the guide is that they are appending updated values to the `newRev` value, while it should be appended to it's `newRev.properties` var.

So I made a new NSDictionary variable and added it to the existing one.

```
var properties = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
properties[PROPERTY_DOCUMENT_TYPE] = String(DOCUMENT_TYPE_USERS)

document.update({ (newRev) -> Bool in

    newRev.properties.addEntriesFromDictionary(properties)

        return true

}, error: &error)
```